# Get TFS URL in Portal Site

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, moss

I have created a Team Project in TFS 2010 and the Project Portal in SharePoint 2010.

Now I need to create a WebPart to deploy in the SharePoint Site (Project portal) that connects to the TFS to get some information.

Where I can get the TFS Url that is associated with the Project Portal in SharePoint?

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url of TFS is not stored in the Project Portal. It is the other way round. In TFS the WSS url is stored.

Comment: But somehow when I edit the queryResultWebPart the WebParts knows the connection to TFS. Thanks Ewald.

Comment: Just a thought... When you edit that webpart, isn't that a setting of the webpart itself. It is possible that when creating a new site, the webpart is added to the page during the provisioning and the setting is set by TFS.

Comment: Not quite. See my answer regarding TfsRedirect.aspx

Answer (score 0):

TfsRedirect can be used to determine the TFS Web Access URL from within SharePoint. Although it's not exactly what you want, and it's a little hacky - you can pass the parameter `tf:Test=1` to get the TFS team project that is associated with the site that your web part is being displayed on.

See John Socha-Leialoha's blog post on [Using TfsRedirect to Display Reports in TFS 2010 Dashboards](http://blogs.socha.com/2010/07/using-tfsredirect-to-display-reports-in.html)

> **What is TfsRedirect?**
>
> Here’s the scenario. You had TFS create a dashboard site in SharePoint
> when you created your team project (or you added it later as described
> here). There are several items on this dashboard that point to other
> locations that are potentially on other servers:
>
> - Team Web Access
> - Process Guidance
> - Reports shown on the dashboard pages
>
> TFS itself know where to find these assets. And the locations can
> change if, for example, the TFS administrator moves the reports to a
> different server.
>
> Rather than hard-code the locations of these assets into the
> dashboard, **the TFS team created a web page called TfsRedirect.aspx
> that knows where these different assets are located, and will redirect
> to that page.**

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't you be able to go in to TFS2010 -> Team Explorer -> Right-Click on your Team Project -> Portal Settings?

Comment: a) The original post is asking about getting the TFS URI from the portal site, not the other way around.  b) The original post is asking how to do it programatically.